# Grep lines for numbers greater than given number

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I'm trying to grep for lines in the first field of an output that are greater than a given number.  In this instance, that number is `755`.  Ultimately, what I'm doing is trying to list every file with privileges greater than (and not equal to) `755` by using `stat -c '%a %n' *` and then pipe to some grep'ing (or possibly sed'ing?) to obtain this final list.  Any ideas how this could best be accomplished?

Comment: Since `755` is really an octal number representing a sequence of bits, what exactly does "greater than" mean? `666` gives everyone write access; is that "greater than" `755`? Is `755` "greater than" `666`?

Comment: OS X users: The equivalent of `stat -c '%a %n' *` (Linux) appears to be `stat -f '%Lp %N' *`

Comment: the person is asking for grep, while people still giving awk?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

try this:

```
stat -c '%a %n' *|awk '$1>755'
```

if you just want the filename in your final output, skip the privilege numbers, you could:

```
stat -c '%a %n' *|awk '$1>755{print $2}'
```

**EDIT**

actually you could do the `chmod` within awk. but you should make sure the user execute the awk line has the permission to change those files.

```
stat -c '%a %n' *|awk '$1>755{system("chmod 755 "$2)}'
```

again, assume the filename has no spaces.

Comment: Oh thanks for that little add-on.  I was just going to cut out field 2, but yours accomplishes it in one less pipe!

Comment: Watch out for filenames with spaces.

Comment: @user2150250 note, my 2nd awk one-liner assumes that your filename has no space.

Comment: @CarlNorum ha... 20 secs.. I just wanted to remind OP the same thing

Comment: Haha, yeah I don't have to worry about spaces in the file names but thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Kent Could I ask one more question? How could I pipe this list of files to a chmod 755 so it chmod's all the files in the output?

Comment: @Carl Norum Hmm ... for some reason that isn't working for me. That's what I was trying originally but it doesn't seem to be successfully changing permissions on any of the files in my list. My full command is `cat /etc/shells | xargs stat -c '%a %n' | awk '$1>755{print $2}' | xargs chmod 755`

Comment: You probably don't want a numeric comparison with 755 here -- for example, 770 is numerically greater than 755, but 707 and 077 are numerically less. Also, if what you really want to do is remove write access for group and other, just use `chmod go-w`.

Comment: @user2150250 `|xargs chmod 755` should work. has the current use permission to change those `shell` files?

Comment: @user2150250 you could actually do the chmod within awk, see the EDIT in ansewr.

Answer (score 7):

I'd use [`awk(1)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/awk/):

```
stat -c '%a %n' * | awk '$1 > 755'
```

The `awk` pattern matches lines where the first field is greater then 755.  You could add an action if you want to print a subset of a line or something different, too (See @Kent's answer).

Answer (score 4):

Neither `grep` nor `sed` are good at arithmetics. `awk` could help (unfortunately I don't know it). But note that `find` can be handy here, too:

```
   -perm mode
          File's permission bits are exactly  mode  (octal  or  symbolic).
          Since  an  exact match is required, if you want to use this form
          for symbolic modes, you may have to  specify  a  rather  complex
          mode  string.  For example -perm g=w will only match files which
          have mode 0020 (that is, ones for which group  write  permission
          is  the  only  permission set).  It is more likely that you will
          want to use the `/' or `-' forms, for example -perm -g=w,  which
          matches  any file with group write permission.  See the EXAMPLES
          section for some illustrative examples.

   -perm -mode
          All of the permission bits mode are set for the file.   Symbolic
          modes  are accepted in this form, and this is usually the way in
          which would want to use them.  You must specify `u', `g' or  `o'
          if  you use a symbolic mode.   See the EXAMPLES section for some
          illustrative examples.

   -perm /mode
          Any of the permission bits mode are set for the file.   Symbolic
          modes  are  accepted in this form.  You must specify `u', `g' or
          `o' if you use a symbolic mode.  See the  EXAMPLES  section  for
          some  illustrative  examples.  If no permission bits in mode are
          set, this test matches any file (the idea here is to be  consis‐
          tent with the behaviour of -perm -000).
```

So what could work for you is:

```
find . -perm -755 -printf '%m %p\n'
```

Just remove the `-printf` part if you only need filenames.